# How can i operate two mongodb query synchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, synchronization

I am writing a shortenUrl API with Node.js and MongoDB.

I am using a collection for storing the incrementing ID.

Every time user asks for a shortened URL,

- The server will ask the `database` for the newest available numberID,
- Then do a base62 transformation.

  However, because of the async feature of Nodejs, the finish time of obtaining incrementing ID and inserting new URL pair is not sure. Sometimes the server inserts the URL pair without the incrementing ID.

  ```
    app.post("/" , function(req , res) {
              const curLongUrl = req.body.longUrl;
              const data = {
                  longUrl : curLongUrl,
                  shortUrl : ""
              }; 
       const IDurl = "https://shortenurl-rustyblade.c9users.io/";

          mongo.connect(url , function(err , db) {
          if(err) { 
              return console.log(err);
          }

          const increment = db.collection("autoIncrement");
          increment.findOne({"function" : "incrementKey"} , function(err , docs) {
              if(err) {
                  return console.log(err);
              }
              const curID = docs.increment;
              console.log(curID);
              const curShortUrl = IDurl + curID;
              data.shortUrl = curShortUrl;
              db.close();
          });
      });


      mongo.connect(url , function(err , db) {
          if(err) { 
              return console.log(err);
          }    
          const col = db.collection("urlTable");
          col.insert(data , function(err , document) {
              if(err) { 
                  return console.log(err);
              }
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
              db.close();
              res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
          });
      });
      //res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
  ```

Comment: Please read the documentation and search out for the node async nature , this type of question are asked may time .check async method and promises . I would say see this first before coding start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like:

```
yourAPI("/", function () {
    // ...

    increment(function () {
        // ...

        // if increase success

        urlTableInsert(..., function () {
            // ...

            //  if insert success
            db.close();
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
    })
})
```

And you could use Promise, co or Async/await etc. to solve the Callback Hell problem.